# Write method that checks if a given number (positive integer) contains digit 3. If it is true answer is true.if it is false answer is false.in C#

Tags: c#

Do not convert number to other type. Do not use built-in functions like `Contains()`, `StartsWith()`, etc.

```
while (number > 0)
{
      if (number % 10 == 3)
      {  
          return true;
      }
      number /= 10;
  }
 return false;`
```

Comment: what _is_ the question/problem exactly? BTW if you to check the int length you can simply do `number .ToString().Length;`

Comment: @styx How would `number .ToString().Length` help here?

Comment: @styx, `ToString` will convert it's type.  OP: Are you getting an error, is your algorithm not working? What is your problem?

Comment: @KlausGütter  i understood the question as to check if the length of the int is 3, but it seems he wants to check if the number 3 is part of a given int

Comment: @styx "contains digit" seems rather clear to me. But the first part of your comment is very true.

Comment: What is the type of `number`? if it's an int, than `if(number > 99 && number < 1000)` -> `number` has exactly 3 digits. If it's a string, than you can check it's length (which is not a built in function, it's a property).

Comment: It is ok, but I want output for, If we enter any number then it check whether the number contains digit 3.. answer must be true..if it is not, itz false..like that                 
 outPut => please Enter number - 123455                                     
                   True                                        
                   Please enter number  - 155677                             
                   False

Answer (score 0):

> Method that checks if given number (positive integer) **contains digit 3**

You were nearly there

```
private static bool HasDigit(int num,int digit)
{
   while (num > 0)
   {
      if(num % 10 == digit)
         return true;
      num /= 10;
   }
   return false;
}
```

**Usage**

```
Console.WriteLine(HasDigit(1222, 3));
Console.WriteLine(HasDigit(23345, 3));
```

**Output**

```
False
True
```

Other approaches might be

```
private static bool HasDigit2(int num, int digit)
{
   var str = num.ToString();
   for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
      if (str[i] == ((char) digit) + '0')
         return true;
   return false;
}
```

Or

```
private static bool HasDigit3(int num, int digit)
   => num.ToString().Any(t => t == ((char) digit) + '0');
```

Comment: It is ok, but I want output for, If we enter any number then it check whether the number contains digit 3.. answer must be true..if it is not, itz false..like that                 
 outPut => please Enter number - 123455                                     
                   True                                        
                   Please enter number  - 155677                             
                   False

Comment: @UviniDiyawadana Pass the number that you entered to the function HasDigit and display the output wherever necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive solution:

```
public static bool Contains3(int n) {
            if (n < 10) {
                if (n == 3) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return n % 10 == 3 || Contains3(n / 10);
        }
```